# SQL query to get data with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database.

```
A | B | C
--+---+---
1 |11 |  0
1 |12 |  0
1 |13 |  0
2 |33 |  5
2 |34 | 10
2 |35 | 78
5 |45 |  0
5 |49 |  0
5 |51 |  1
8 |10 |  0
8 |14 |  2
8 |34 |  3
```

I am looking for sql query to fetch distinct A value which is having at least one value of C is zero but should not all the values would be zero.
In the above table I should get 5 & 8

At the moment for A value which is having all values are zero , I am doing like as below so something similar would be helpful

```
SUM(ABS(table.C)) = 0
```

Comment: Take a moment and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Cant be mysql and sql-server

Comment: Already mentioned on the top as this is sql server

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Already mentioned in the description. I am looking for sql query to fetch distinct A value which is having at least one value of C is zero but should not all the values would be zero. In the above table I should get 5 & 8

Answer (score 2):

If `C` is never negative:

```
select A
from mytable
group by A
having min(C) = 0
   and max(C) > 0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf38bef0fad5a4efa4280cd02091bbdc)

If `C` can be negative:

```
select A
from mytable
group by A
having min(abs(C)) = 0
   and max(abs(C)) > 0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da69bcda8b744bed45a4802e33259c71)

And there are many other ways:

```
select distinct t0.A
from mytable t0
join mytable t1 on t1.A = t0.A
where t0.C = 0
  and t1.C <> 0;
```

```
select distinct t0.A
from mytable t0
where t0.C = 0
  and exists (
    select *
    from mytable t1
    where t1.A = t0.A
      and t1.C <> 0
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using `exists`

```
select A from table
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t1.A=t2.A
                  and t2.c=0)
 group by A
 having sum(c)<>0
```

Comment: you might want SUM(ABS(c)) to avoid -1 1 summing to 0. Not sure if it is possible as negatives aren't in the sample

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
;with zeros as
(
select distinct colA
from table
where ColC=0
)

select distinct colA
from table
   join zeros on table.ColA=zeros.ColA
where table.ColC <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select distinct a
from my_table t
where t.a in (select x.a from my_table x where x.c = 0)
  and t.a in (select x.a from my_table x where x.c <> 0)
```